# Dynamics AX Suppress Column in Two-Column Replacement Key

Tags: lookup, axapta, replace, dynamics-ax-2012

I'm using replacement keys to clean up forms with foreign keys.  Single column replacements work great.  Multi-column replacement keys work fine, but the presentation isn't great if one of those columns in that index isn't meant for users to see.

Is there a way to suppress the display of one or more columns in a multi-column replacement key?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making the field invisible?

But how can the user create the relation, if she cannot enter all the fields?

Answer (score 0):

The best and easiest way to do it would be to go to the reference group control on the form and choosing the ReferenceFieldGroup that you want to use to show fields. (Choose a group you created yourself with only the fields you want. AutoIdentification is the default for this control)

Another way to do it would be to use a custom reference table lookup as seen in the example of the following link.

[Display filtered data in reference](http://yasirnedian.blogspot.com/2012/10/x-code-to-modifyset-properties-of-aot.html)

There they build a custom lookup to filter things, but you could use the same to specify the fields you want to see in the lookup. (Would be recommended method if you also need special filters, ...)

But do keep in mind what Jan Kjeldsen says! : How are they going to create the relation if they do not have all the fields...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar case. For example if you have three tables:

```
attribute 1
attribute 2
attribute 3
```

`table 2` has attributes that are linked to `attribute 1` and `table 3` has attributes linked to `table 2`. So you have:

```
attribute 1 with rec id & code
attribute2 with recid code and attribute 1 recid
attribute2 with recid code and attribute 2 recid
```

You create a replacement key for this, but in the form you dont want to see

```
attribute one: attribute1
attribute two: attribue 1 attribute 2
attribute three: attribute 1 attribue 2 attribute 3
```

So you want to make the 'link' fields invisible. I did this by changing the auto identification group to AutoPopulate "No" and removed all fields that I didn't want to see.